# How is insertAdjacentHTML so much faster than innerHTML?

Tags: html, performance, browser, innerhtml

[About a month ago](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/aurora8/), Firefox 8 implemented the insertAdjacentHTML method, which was added to IE4 along with innerHTML. According to [this](http://jsperf.com/insertadjacenthtml) benchmark, insertAdjacentHTML is usually **an order of magnitude** faster than innerHTML.

I assume both call the same HTML parser, so why is the difference that dramatic? insertAdjacentHTML is a simple method call, whereas innerHTML is a getter/setter and there's probably a bit of overhead for that, but I would never imagine that much.

Comment: Note that using `appendChild` is much faster than both. Probably because no parser is needed there.
The difference between `insertAdjacentHTML` and `innerHTML` seems insignificant when compared to `appendChild`. However, if you do need to parse the html string, `appendChild` won't help much. Here's a detailed JSperf: http://jsperf.com/insertadjacenthtml-perf/28

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`work.innerHTML += "<span>test</span>";` is equivalent to `work.innerHTML = work.innerHTML + "<span>test</span>";`, i.e. each time it runs it has to serialise all the existing contents of `work` and then reparse the whole lot, plus the additional span.

`work.insertAdjacentHTML("BeforeEnd", "<span>test</span>");` is only parsing the one span each time and then attaching the small document fragment to the DOM.

Comment: I would hope a good browser would optimize `work.innerHTML += "<span>test</span>"` to simply append to `innerHTML`, just like modern browsers optimize string concatenation. I could be wrong though, but it would be surprising if none of the browser vendors had thought of this.

Comment: It's not so easy as that. The serialize/parse cycle has a number of side effects, such as resetting some node properties and dropping dynamically attached event handlers. Optimizing would require those to be replicated exactly. The browser manufacturers have better things to be doing. `Element.innerHTML += ...` is an anti-pattern that's easy to avoid in JS code. Just don't do it.

Comment: +1 Makes sense. I disagree with `e.innerHTML += ...` being an antipattern though. There are some valid uses involving Ajax and I don't see why it's harmful (aside from being slow) elsewhere.

Comment: @alpha123 `There are some valid uses involving Ajax` what do you mean here?

Comment: `e.innerHTML+=...` is vastly used nowdays. In 90% of cases it can be replaced by insertAdjacentHTML, however for some reason most JSers simply never heard of it. It's an educational problem now...

Answer (score 1):

The `innerHTML` setter will have to remove all existing child nodes prior to adding new ones.

Don't know if this is the only reason, but that's certainly a factor.